# how to check if a date is three days before today

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hey i would like to know if there is any script (php) that could check if a specified date three days before today.

say..

```
$d1 = date("Y-m-d", filemtime($testfile));
$d2 = date("Y-m-d");
```

now i would like to know how to compare this two dates to check if d1 is atleast 3days ago or before d2
any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: `if(strtotime($d1)-(60*60*24) <= time()-(60*60*24) || strtotime($d1) < strtotime($d2))` is something of what your looking for.

Comment: I bet this has been asked and answered already. Please use the search first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check it with timestamp:

```
if (time() - filemtime($testfile) >= 3 * 86400) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not to use DateTime object.

```
 $d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',filemtime($testfile));
 $d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
 $interval = $d1->diff($d2);
 $diff = $interval->format('%a');
 if($diff>3){
 }
 else {
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you wish to test whether the file was modified more than three days ago:

```
if (filemtime($testfile) < strtotime('-3 days')) {
   // file modification time is more than three days ago
}
```

Comment: how do i tweak it to check it its not up to three days from last modified.

Comment: @VyrenMedia I'm not sure I understand ... "not up to three days" translates to "at least three days" ... so my answer is just one second off? If you compare using `<=` you should have what you want I think.

Answer (score 1):

use `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 day"));` for specific date

you can also use

```
strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 day")));
```

to convert it to integer before comparing a date string

Answer (score 1):

well, stunned to see no one is using mktime() function,
it makes the job simple

for example your input date is :10/10/2012

mktime convert it to unix time stamp

```
$check_date=mktime(0,0,0,10,**10+3**,2012);
```

we can perform any operations weather +,-,*,/

Comment: i dont understand how this tries to solve my problem..please explain your code and how i solves my problem

Comment: mktime(). function converts the time given into a unix time stamp. here in my example i am adding +3days  to current days

Answer (score 0):

use timestamp instead of date,

```
$d1 = filemtime($testfile);
$now = time();
if ($now - $d1 > 3600*24*3) {
  ..
}
```